# Date_query problems

Tags: search, date-query

I need to modify search query in my theme to add `date_query` with 'after' param based on option value from form select.

Here's what I got so far:

Inside form my select looks like:

```
<select class="select-date" id="select-date">                           
    <option value="5">For the whole time</option>
    <option value="1">For one day</option>
    <option value="2">For 3 days</option>
    <option value="3">For week</option>
    <option value="4">For month</option>
</select>
```

Values must filter content based on date posts were posted. For example selected value of 3 gives us posts published in the last week.

Than I get some code to get value from selected and conditionals to change 'after' param in query. Here's how it looks like

```
<?php
    $dato_query = array();
    $date_z = $_GET['select-date'];
    if ($date_z == '1'){
        $dato_query['after'] = '1 day ago';
    }
    elseif ($date_z == '2'){
        $dato_query['after'] = '3 days ago';
    }
    elseif($date_z == '3') {
        $dato_query['after'] = '1 week ago';
    }
    elseif ($date_z == '4'){
        $dato_query['after'] = '1 month ago';
    }
    else {
        $dato_query['after'] = '5 years ago';
    }

    $dato_query =  apply_filters( 'jm_job_search_data_query', $dato_query, $REQUEST );

    if( !empty( $dato_query ) ) {
        $dato_query['relation'] = 'AND';
        if( is_object( $query ) && get_class( $query ) == 'WP_Query' ) {
            $query->date_query->queries = $dato_query;
            $query->query_vars['date_query'][] = $query->date_query->queries;
        } elseif( is_array( $query ) ) {
            $query['date_query'] = $dato_query;
        }
    }
?>
```

And after that I get only else state result: - 5 years ago.

So `date_query` is added to my search query, but it don't relays on select choices.

I hope someone can help me. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code returns the posts belonging to 5 years ago, then I assume your problem is in the conditionals, since none of them are run.

The form elements must have a name if you want to get their values in the back-end. Your select lacks a name, and you are trying to get its value by using its ID. You should use it this way instead:

```
<select class="select-date" name="select-date" id="select-date">
...
</select>
```

Now you can have access to `$_GET['select-date']` on the server.

Comment: oh, wow. Really forgot about that) I`ll try to add name and will write about result i`m getting. Thank You Good Friend)

Comment: Pazhalsta! It's these small things that sometimes annoy us for days :)

Comment: And all okay) 
Really appreciate this help)
Have a nice day)
With love from Ukraine, Andrey)